# using google image to convert list of words in python

Tags: python, pandas, google-api

I have a pandas dataframe containing a bunch of words describing professions in a language that I do not know (it could be english, dutch, german...whatever).
The list of words might contain errors.

```
import pandas
df = pandas.DataFrame(data=['teacer','leraar','insegniaante','designer'],columns = ['professions'])
```

What I would like to do is:

- To search in google image for the word,
- take the first image
- download the first tags associated

In short I would like to use google image to rename my original set of words taking advantage of the ability of google of ignoring the spelling mistakes when looking for images. Is that possible? Could you help me in building such script?

Answer (score 1):

Look into the requests library for interfacing with the google image search.

http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/